# Relation between stress and resistance in a block of metal

Tags: classical-mechanics, stress-strain

I opened up my broken electronic weighing balance to understand how  the machine actually calculates the weight of things.
To my surprise, instead of a pressure sensor I found a setup with a metal cuboid which had two wires attached each attached to the bottom and top of the metal cuboid.
[image: Weighing scale mechanism]

The load is applied to the end with a hole that screws on the plastic tray that holds the weight to be measured. From this set up I can figured out that the weight calculation mainly depends on a change in resistance due to the elastic deformation of this metal cuboid.

But I have no idea how to represent this mathematically with my high school knowledge. I think a relationship between stress and resistance is a good way to go but I don’t know how to go about it.

Comment: I couldn’t find anything online regarding this that I could understand. I’m not sure if this is the right site to post about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess that under the white stuff in the picture there is a   [strain gauge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strain_gauge) which measures how much the metal bar bends under the weight applied to the end.

When the bar bends, the top surface will be stretched and the bottom surface compressed. The strain gauge converts the amount of stretch into a change in electrical resistance.

The holes drilled through the beam underneath the gauge make the beam more flexible at that position along its length, to increase the amount of bending and therefore increase the electrical signal from the strain gauge.

Using two gauges on each surface of the beam cancels out signals caused by other reasons the beam might change shape, for example thermal expansion. If the beam expands because it gets hot, both gauges produce the same change in output. If the beam bends, they produce equal and opposite changes. Therefore, detecting the *difference* in output between the two gauges cancels out effect of thermal expansion.